# Clear shop cache issue in shopware 5.6.2

Tags: caching, admin, logout, shopware

I am using Shopware 5.6.2. When I am trying to clear the cache from Configuration->cache/Perforamnce->clear shop cache

The clear cache ajax request is pending for some time and the admin side will be automatically logout.

[image: Shopware files info in System info]

Can anybody help me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please answer the following questions?

Your Shopware files are not the core files. Did you edit some of them?
Which Shopware version are you on?
Could you provide the shopware logs?

Altough you can take a look at the network-tab. There could be 500-HTTP-Response

Comment: The issue resolved when I have updated the shopware version to 5.6.3. Thank you